# How can I add rows to a Google Web Toolkit flextable in the UiBinder?

Tags: gwt, flextable

Where can I find a [UiBinder](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/UiBinder) template for the FlexTable?

I am using [Google Web Toolkit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Web_Toolkit) (GWT).

Answer (score 7):

I found a [link text](http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/browse_thread/thread/725505d2ced16adf/bee2fd346dcbf0f7?lnk=raot) that said if you do not need to handle events, you can just use straight HTML instead of FlexTable for layout:

```
<g:HTMLPanel>
   <table>
    <tr><td>Info:</td><td><g:TextBox ui:field="infoTextBox"/></td></tr>
  </table>
</g:HTMLPanel>
```

Answer (score 5):

AFAIK, there's no custom "template" for `FlexTable` (as there is for, for example, [`DockLayoutPanel`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/DockLayoutPanel.html)). Besides, `FlexTable` is used when you have content added/removed dynamically - which means you won't be adding stuff via UiBinder templates (that doesn't even makes sense), you'd do that in the class bound to that UiBinder template. The same goes for initial content of the table - you just have to insert it programmatically.